# Extra space on the right side

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a website: www.ribbonhill.co.uk
I have been trying to remove a white space on the right, which appears on mobile phone.

Strangely it doesn't appear on full mode on both Chrome and Edge browsers, but when it is resized small the problem only appears on Edge but not on Chrome.

The site was built using Django-oscar and itself didn't have any issues.

I have tried removing two CSS files and there is no white space. These two files are ribbonhill.css and w3.css.

By removing w3.css there is only a small white space but removing ribbomhill.css leaves a large space.

I have been trying to remove a few codes but struggling.

I have tried

```css
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){

  html,
  body{
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
  }

}
```

And

```css
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

But still no luck.

Update:
Sorted on mobile phones and chrome but edge / internet explorer showing below?! I guess I will just leave it as it is[image]

Comment: Why do you need to check mobile-sized page via edge?

Comment: I noticed it happens when using my mobile ( only tiny bit) but I thought it would be good to try to remove it and I happen to notice the problem more in Edge.

Comment: Can you show me the capture image?

Answer (score 1):

I have analyzed your webiste [www.ribbonhill.co.uk](http://www.ribbonhill.co.uk). Its a small CSS mismatch .

1. Inside the `navbar` remove the `min-width: 400px;` for your site logo and `width:80%` its not a vaild input value.

Change your CSS as follow:

> .logo {
>       margin-left: 50%;
>       transform: translateX(-50%);
>       min-width: auto !important;  }

2. Remove the `padding: 2rem 0 0;` for your `.footer` class. because its affecting the container padding.

It should be like that:

> .footer, footer {padding-top: 20rem;margin-bottom: 0rem; }

Comment: All sorted! It is all okay on mobile phones and chrome, although I can still drag the webpage to right on Edge or internet explorer browser, which still shows some white spaces. I guess it is something to do with the browser? Strangely there is no scroll button at the bottom but only happens when dragging. (will attach the screenshot above). Thank you for the comment! so much happier.